# Can I use 'having' in a noun clause?

Tags: conjunctions, gerunds, present-participles, noun-phrases

Let's say there is a person in a room who has a blue pen in his hand. Can I say something like this:

- Whom should I ask from?
- The one having a blue pen

Or I only have to answer like this

- The one who has a blue pen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The one having a blue pen* is grammatically impeccable, but impossibly literary. This sort of utterance is unlikely to appear in a formal context, and practically no Anglo-American speaker today (and very few in the past) would express that meaning with *having*. We'd say

> The one **with** a blue pen.

And even that is fairly stiff: in actual speech pronominal *one* is rarely used except to allude to a member of a previously defined category:

- Which monitor/teacher/clerk/&c should I ask?
- The one with the blue pen.

But with uncategorized *who* rather than categorized *which*, most people would use the appropriate noun:

- Who should I ask?
- The guy/woman/kid/&c with the blue pen.

If you have no idea who will have the blue pen, use a fused relative:

> Whoever has the blue pen.

Comment: +1 Great answer. But why "Who" instead of "Whom"?

Comment: @SovereignSun Because as I said, this sort of exchange is characteristic of improvised spoken English, and practically nobody--even me, the pickiest and most pedantic speaker you are ever likely to encounter--uses *whom* in speech.

Comment: As William Zinsser says, "Bad writing makes bright people look dumb". I don't wish to offend you but let's teach learners proper spoken and written English and explain the difference, I agree that **"Whom"** is rather stilted to the modern ear and therefore less common but it's grammatically correct in these examples. We are trying to teach non-native speakers proper formal English and spoken English, so we should give credit to what we are explaining.

Comment: @SovereignSun 'Proper' and 'correct' English is the English proper to the specific context and speech community in which it is used. And our users have a very wide variety of purposes: some are eager to master academic English, some colloquial English suited to commercial environments--and some have a sound knowledge of academic English but need to understand the vernacular used in songs and movies, and in striking up  conversations in bars with attractive strangers.

Comment: I totally agree with you.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, but : The one having a tantrum / The one having a brother. This is a stative verb problem aint it? (See my answer below)

Comment: @Araucaria Absolutely. I was thinking about introducing that, but then work [MAYNARD G. KREBS: *Work!*] intervened.

Answer (score 4):

> *The one having a blue pen. (ungrammatical with this meaning)

The sentence above would be regarded as ungrammatical by most native speakers when used to convey the meaning *the one who has a blue pen*. It uses an *-ing* clause *having a blue pen* to modify the common noun *one*.

Why would people consider it ungrammatical? That's a good question!

We can split verb phrases into two types. Some verb phrases describe actions, for example:

- She's eating an ice-cream.
- The elephants are dancing the tango.
- We play tennis every Thursday.

Above we see examples of actions such as eating, dancing or playing tennis. Other verb phrases describe situations instead of actions:

- She has a brother.
- I don't like cheese.
- I know Bob.

We normally only use *ing* clauses to modify nouns when they describe *actions*. We don't use them when they describe situations or states. The following examples are fine because they describe actions:

- The one eating an ice-cream
- The one dancing the tango
- The one playing tennis

These examples which describe situations, not actions, are wrong:

- *The one having a brother.
- *The one not liking cheese.
- *The one knowing Bob.

**The Original Poster's question**

The Original Poster wants to know if we can use clauses with *having* to describe nouns. The answer is: it depends! If the verb *having* is being used to describe a situation (especially if it describes possession), then we cannot:

- *The one having a pen.

However, if the verb *having* is being used to describe an *action*, then we definitely can:

- The one having a party.
- The one having a tantrum.
- The one having his face painted.

This is similar to how we use *-ing* verbs in present participle constructions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer "The one having a blue pen" is correct, but the question is not correct. There is no preposition after "ask"

We can re-write the sentence as following:

- Whom should I ask?
- The one having a blue pen

In this case, we can understand that:

I should ask the one having a blue pen

Comment: **"Whom should he ask what?"** or **"for what?"**